# I cannot authenticate user with the jwt token in my django project

Tags: django, jwt, bearer-token, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm trying to authenticate a user with jwt token generated in the login view, while copying the jwt token and adding it into the headers for authorization it shows an error and doesn't get authorized:

```
{
    "detail": "Given token not valid for any token type",
    "code": "token_not_valid",
    "messages": [
        {
            "token_class": "AccessToken",
            "token_type": "access",
            "message": "Token is invalid or expired"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my custom user model

```
class CUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    #username = None
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
# models.py
```

```
class loginapi(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            data = request.data
            serializer = LoginSerializer(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                email = request.data['email']
                password = request.data['password']
    
                user = CUser.objects.filter(email=email).first() #check for user.
    
                if user is None:
                    return Response({
                        'status':400,
                        'message':'User not found',
                        'data': {}
                    })
                
                if not user.check_password(password):
                    return Response({
                        'status':400,
                        'message':'Wrong password',
                        'date': {}
                    })
                
    
                payload = {
                    'id': user.id,
                    'exp': timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
                    'iat': timezone.now()
                }
    
                token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
                #token_string = token.decode('utf-8')
                response = Response()
                response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True)      
                response.data = {
                    'jwt':token
                }
                return response
            return Response({
                        'status':400,
                        'message':'Something went wrong',
                        'date': serializer.errors
            })
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'message': str(e)}, status=400)
```

````
```output(print(payload)): eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MTEsImV4cCI6MTcxMTM0ODI0NSwiaWF0IjoxNzExMzQ0NjQ1fQ.iRoq_kPox_N_tPXjFUlhaycPMPpR6kA5QCtC-bNIAy4
```
````

```
class userapi(APIView):
   def get(self, request):
   token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')
   if not token:
      raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated')
   try:
      payload = jwt.decode(token, 'secret', algorithms=\['HS256'\])
      print(payload) 
      except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
          raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated')
      user = CUser.objects.filter(id=payload\['id'\]).first()
      serializer = UserSerializer(user)
   return Response(serializer.data)
```

these are my login and user views
this is the jwt token that's getting generated

```
{
"jwt":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MTEsImV4cCI6MTcxMDk5OTAwNCwiaWF0IjoxNzEwOTk1NDA0fQ.DEY0obelNmMfCsDy1Pv_1w7SAiCwEnmGDKbC6Zz9oxs"
}
```

hope you can help me out now.

Comment: The error message tells you that something is wrong with the token, but you don't show it here, so it's hard to judge what is actually wrong. Please show the exact value of the `token`, that is passed into `jwt.decode(token, ...`. Often the problems are extra characters or even an empty string. But I don't want to guess here.  And please also format the code of `class userapi(APIView):`.

Comment: What you edited in is a valid token (of course, starting from *eyJ...*,  but I asked you to show the exact value that is passed into `jwt.decode(token, ...`. So if you pass the complete JSON *{"jwt":"eyJ...* it is wrong. But I'm afraid that remains unclear in the moment, because it seems you did not answer precicely what I asked. Put a `print(token)` directly before `payload = jwt.decode(token,...` and show the **exact** result.

Comment: The output of the is a valid jwt token